# Get all elements from sharepoint list query via ms graph api

Tags: rest, http, pagination, microsoft-graph-api

I use a `GET` request with the following url to retrieve data from a sharepoint list:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?expand=fields
```

However, in the `value`-key of the response dict i get only 200 entries. The List has roughly 250 entries.

So I guess microsoft graph api has some limitation on how many samples can be requested from the endpoint at once.

I cannot find anything in the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on how I could get the missing entries.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request does not contain all elements the json response contains a key `@odata.nextLink`.

a get request on that link gives you the next 200 entries in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the paramter top=1000 after "expand=fields" to your request.
Don't forget the "&" :)

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?expand=fields&top=1000
```